# Correct html code for facebook status posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to code my website in such order so if someone paste my website's URL in their facebook status update or in their profile page,this post will display correctly,with an image on the side,text parsed from the website.

For example i am posting a screenshot.The one on the **left** is my site.The one on the **right** is some random site.See they have included a picture,a text paragraph,a title and so on....

[image]

Are there any special guideline or rules i should follow or is it out of my powers.
Also,i could even think a search term for googling it so i post it here(dont even know what to search at FB apis).

Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the Facebook Docs. You'll need to include Open Graph tags withinin your `<head>` 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

**From the docs:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
  <title>The Rock (1996)</title>
     <!-- the bold title on Facebook -->
  <meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
  <meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
     <!-- the url under the title on Facebook -->
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
     <!-- the image to the left of text on Facebook -->
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb"/>
  <meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
     <!-- the description under description and title on Facebook -->
  <meta property="og:description"
      content="A group of U.S. Marines, under command of
               a renegade general, take over Alcatraz and
               threaten San Francisco Bay with biological
               weapons."/>
  ...
</head>
```

Comment: hm,i think this will do the job.I accept the answer in a short.

Comment: @Theodoros80 once you place the meta tags on your site it can take a little while for the changes to take place on Facebook! So you might not see instant results.